# How do I call a file from a textfile?

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a text file that I can access & open a directory. This directory contains csv files.
Please refer:

```
export_test_practise-1_2017-06-23_2017-06-23.csv
export_test_practise-1_2017-06-24_2017-06-24.csv
export_test_practise-2_2017-06-24_2017-06-24.csv
```

Now I want to write a number in the second line of the text file (`String nString)`. This number then calls the corresponding csv file.
If several csv files end with the same number, I always want to call the most recent.
For example: *file.txt* has a **1**
-> open `export_test_practise-1_2017-06-24_2017-06-24.csv` (practise-1 with lastModiefiedDate)
Whats the best way to do this?

```
public class Test{
private static void sortFilesByName(File txtFile)
    throws IOException
{
    // Read from the file
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFile));
    String path = br.readLine();
    String nrString = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    File[] fileList = new File(path).listFiles(); 
    // Sort files by name
    Arrays.sort(fileList); 

long mod = 0;
File found = null;
System.out.println("nrString: " + nrString);
for (File f : fileList)
{
    System.out.println(f.getName());

    boolean fileNameOkForNrString = true;
    if (fileNameOkForNrString && f.lastModified() > mod)
    {
        mod = f.lastModified();
        found = f;
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: yoou dont have  list, you have an array... Arrays.sort can help you in this case

Comment: Here are, all files of the `fileList` are traversed and a file is save in `found`.
`Array.sort ()` sorts only the list of files, but have nothing to do with calling from the text file or?

Comment: I don't get what you are asking.  Your question's title suggests that you are asking about how to sort.  But you already have code that will sort the pathnames correctly, at least for the example given.  What exactly is it that you are asking about.  Please **clarify** your Question.  (It is obvious that English is not your first language.  That is OK.  However, you need be able to state your question clearly, or we won't understand it, and we won't be able to answer it.)

Comment: Don´t  you just understand the heading or do not you understand the text likewise?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but you can sort the files by date with something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(fileList, (f1,f2) -> (int)(f1.lastModified()-f2.lastModified()));
```